# achartengine how to change x axis label to strings only

Tags: java, android, label, achartengine

How do i set my x axis to Strings in a bar chart?
I created a XYValueSeries and added to it my values in a loop.

```
int i=0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : sentData_Contacts.entrySet()) 
{
    sentBarValues.add(i, entry.getValue()); 
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, entry.getKey());
    i++;
}
```

To do this is used xyValueSerioes.add but this wants 2 double values. So the next line i got my multi renderer and executed the addXTextLabel. The result was that botht he number of the bar and the string appear on the graph.

How do i remove the number of the graph?

Example of resulting X axis label:'2      myString'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i got solution, maybe somebody can tell me if its correct - add mRenderer.setXLabels(0); after i change the label to remove the last one.

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : sentData_Contacts.entrySet()) 
    {
        sentBarValues.add(i, entry.getValue()); 
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, entry.getKey());
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        i++;
    }
```